# How to check that radiobuttons checked on the page after click on submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please, help with this situation: I have page with radiobuttons:

```
<label>Delivery type:</label>
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="7" class="delivery-item" id="del-type-7"  onclick=""><label class="label" for="del-type-7">From our office</label>
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="6" class="delivery-item" id="del-type-6" onclick=""><label class="label" for="del-type-6">Mail Service</label>
<input type="radio" name="delivery" value="5" class="delivery-item" id="del-type-5" onclick=""><label class="label" for="del-type-5">AIR MAIL</label>
<input type="button" value="Submit order" id="order-button">
```

How can I checked by jquery if any radiobutton is checked after pressing submit button? And if they are not, then make the alert window with text: "Please, choose delivery type". Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `:checked` selector, and test the `length`. If it's `0`, there are no selected radio buttons:

```
$('#order-button').click(function() {
    if (!$('.delivery-item:checked').length) {
        alert('Please, choose delivery type...');
    }
});
```

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5s34/)

Comment: Using the .length() gave me errors in FF for this not being a function...  (with jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.9.0)

Using the .is(':checked') as described in the 3rd answer here worked very nicely.

Comment: @marklark Note that `length` is a property not a method, so it doesn't need the trailing brackets. Eg. `foo.length`, ***not*** `foo.length()`

Answer (score 2):

Use jquery [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)/[.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) and [:checked](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) selector.Try this:

```
$('#order-button').click(function() {
    if (!$('.delivery-item').is(':checked')) {
        alert('Please choose delivery type');
    }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/2N5tz/1/)

or

```
$('#order-button').click(function() {
        if (!$('.delivery-item').prop(':checked')) {
            alert('Please choose delivery type');
        }
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/2N5tz/)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that works without you having to specify code for each `input`:

```
$('#order-button').click(function() {
    var elementCount = $('.delivery-item').length;
    var temporaryInteger = 0;
    $(".delivery-item").each(function(){
        if(!($(this).is(':checked'))){
            temporaryInteger++;
        } 
    });
    if(temporaryInteger === elementCount){
        alert("Please, choose delivery type");
    }
});
```

The code above loops through each element with the class `delivery-item` and manipulates a variable to determine whether the alert will display.

Sample JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/L45v9/

EDIT: This code is far less elegant compared to those of the other answerers. Use theirs!